# ASP.NET Login control unable to restore status of "Remember Me" checkbox

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have a login control supporting "Remember Me" option.
The Markup

```
<asp:Login ID="UsersLogin" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="UsersLogin_Authenticate" DisplayRememberMe="true"
            CssClass="usersLogin" FailureText="The username or password you supplied is incorrect"
            Width="100%">
</asp:Login>
```

The Code-behind:

```
protected void UsersLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate(); // Executes the validation controls against the input controls.
    if (!Page.IsValid) return; // Return from the function, incase validation fails.
    e.Authenticated = Membership.ValidateUser(UsersLogin.UserName, UsersLogin.Password);
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UsersLogin.UserName, UsersLogin.RememberMeSet);
}
```

Steps performed and my observations (might be incorrect):
1). User enters the credentials and checks the "Remember Me" check box. ASP.NET will create a persistent cookie on the client side.
2). ASP.NET then navigates the user to some protected resource as indicated by "returnUrl" query string parameter, if available. Otherwise it will redirect the user to the page as specified in the "DefaultUrl" property of  tag in web.config.
3). User closes the browser.
4). User reopens the browser, and types the url to the same protected resource. ASP.NET will grant access to that protected resource, because of the persistent cookie.
5). Now user navigates to the login page. ASP.NET should populate the username and password text box and also check the "Remember Me" check box.

The step 5 is where I am stuck. I'm not sure whether its the responsibility of ASP.NET to ensure step 5.
I'm aware this problem has been asked many a times, but I haven't found a reasonable solution, as many were just workarounds. Some solution suggested to create your own FormsAuthenticationTicket and add UserData to store the remember Me status. Rest suggested to explicitly write down the  tag in web.config and explicitly specifying every parameter including timeout, path etc.

Also correct me on this statement:
"ASP.NET will delete the persistent cookie if we log out from the application, either by clicking the "LoginStatus" control or by having a normal link button and writing
`"FormsAuthentication.Log(); 
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()"`
on the click of normal link button".

Please advice, what needs to be done so that I can make the login control check the Remember Me checked.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the solution. This is what I did to get the check box checked.

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        FormsIdentity identity = User.Identity as FormsIdentity;
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = identity.Ticket;
        if (ticket.IsPersistent)
        {
            UsersLogin.RememberMeSet = true;                    
        }            
    }
```

If the user had checked the Remember Me check box, the ticket would be a persistent ticket.

Thanks anyways.